# How to get navigation params from react-navigation outside the render method?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a dashboard component. Which is having a button like this,

```
onPress= {()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('RenderMeeting',{
  meetingName: meeting.meetingname
})}}
```

Now I have another component called Render meeting component. Which shall display the meeting name on the header. I have done this.

```
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
title: this.props.navigation.getParam('meetingName','sdfsdf'),
    })
```

Now while rendering I am getting a undefined is not an Object evaluating 'RenderMeetingScreen.props.navigate'. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> you can simply get the params like:
>   `this.props.navigation.state.params.meetingName` anywhere in your
>   component.

Answer (score -1):

You can get it even inside your constructor like below:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const{navigation}=this.props;
    this.state = {
      title : navigation.getParam('meetingName')
    }
}
```